# Reload Ajax Content from on.Change function after Page has been refreshed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use a dropdown menu where the user can select specific subjects. If a subject is selected via dropdown, a textbox pops up via ajax and the user can enter stuff.

The problem is that if the form has been submitted and stuff in the form was missing or if the user simply refreshes the page, the ajax content (the text box) disappears and only shows up again, when another subject is selected.

This probably stems from my ajax script, which uses `change` and thus only puts the ajax-input into the div when the dropdown is changed again:

```
$(function() {
$('#subjectapp1').change(function()
{
var self = $(this);

$.post("/blabla/potatoe/subjectpartial1.php",
{
subject1: self.val()
},
function(data)
{
    $('#subjectqualidiv1').html(data);
});

});
});
```

My dropdown menu:

```
<select name="subject1" id="subjectapp1">
<option value="">Please choose</option>
<?php foreach ($subjects as $subject){ ?>
  <option <?php if ($_POST['subject1'] == $fach['subject_id']) {echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $subject['subject_id']; ?>"><?php echo $subject['subject']; ?></option>
```

The div it is loaded into:

```
<div id="subjectqualidiv1"></div>
```

The ajax content (`subjectpartial1.php`) simply contains a text box in which the user can enter his qualification.

Is there a possibility that the ajax content is automatically loaded into the div when the page refreshes without the need to change the subjects again?

**EDIT (WORKS):** Based on the comments I tried the following, which yields the desired result:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// For loading the ajax content on refresh/form submit
    var subject1 = $('#subjectapp1');

$.post("/blabla/potatoe/subjectpartial1.php",
{
subject1: subject1.val()
},
function(data)
{
    $('#subjectqualidiv1').html(data);
}); 

$('#subjectapp1').change(function()
{
var self = $(this);

$.post("/blabla/potatoe/subjectpartial1.php",
{
subject1: self.val()
},
function(data)
{
    $('#subjectqualidiv1').html(data);
});

});
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes - you can put the AJAX directly in the document ready handler. You'll also need to be able to call it from the change event.

Comment: The best way to acheive this while still being able to call your code within an `onchange` event would be to put it into a function and then call it from within the `$(document).ready()` function, which is executed when the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your function that calls your AJAX to the `$(document).ready()` function which executes on page load. Be careful to check for valid data before executing your function because there may be instances when the page loads and the selector will be empty. For missing information you may want to look into the `required` attribute in HTML, which will prevent form submission if no data exists for that element. That will prevent a refresh for insufficient data.

Comment: I inserted the code into the `$(document).ready()` function as well as the trigger for the event and it works now, thanks! What exactly do you mean with check for valid data? Is it not just fired when the value is not empty?

Comment: When you refresh or initially load a page the `$(document).ready()` will be called when your page loads, but most data should be empty due to default browser behavior for these events. Due to this your AJAX call may have empty variables when called within the ready function and may return an error or unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this along with your current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#subjectapp1").trigger('change');
}
```